# How to detect close button action for default manage subscription in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, subscription

I have used showManageSubscriptions function show subscription sheet with subscription options within the application but there is a close button in the sheet which action is not detected, button is clickable though.

```
@available(iOS 15.0.0, *)
    func showManageSubscription(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene) async {
        do {
            try await StoreKit.AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: windowScene)
            print("Sheet is closed")
        } catch {
            print("Sheet can not be opened")
        }
    }
```

Please help me to get the close button action.

Reference link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3803198-showmanagesubscriptions#parameters

Please see screenshot [image]

Comment: I also have the same issue. Have you found a workaround ?

Comment: Not as of now!.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Same here and had this problem also with SwiftUI view modifier `.manageSubscriptionsSheet(isPresented: self.$showManageSubscriptions)`

Comment: This issued was on apple defect. Apple has fixed it iOS 15.4 and later. Please check in latest iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally! I got solution of it.

This was defect from Apple side. Apple has fixed it on iOS 15.4 and later operation system.

Tested ✔️